# Get the last inserted data from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We have a primary key in our table as `UUID`. To get the last record we do order by `desc uuid` field. However, because this field is not integer we do not get the last record always. Is there a way to get the last record? Please note that we do not want to make cluster columns.

Here is my table

```
ArtistId (partition key)  | SongId (primary key, uuid) |  Song
--------------------------------------------
1                         | 9a9fa429-c349-4137         |  abc
1                         | 9a9fa429-b349-6137         |  cde
1                         | 9a9ga429-a349-6132         |  fgh
2                         | 249ga429-a909-6542         |  ijk
2                         | 249kg429-a239-3652         |  lmn
1                         | i55oa429-a909-3462         |  opq
1                         | e4235k59-4ik9-6542         |  rst
```

Comment: Can you show your example table schema and the query itself? AFAIK there's no right way to sort rows in C* by partition key (because OrderedPartitioner was always considered harmful).

Comment: I have edited the question to add the example table, I want the query which will give me the last inserted record in the table.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "last inserted" isn't exactly well-defined in a _distributed_-by-design data store like Cassandra. Last in terms of time? sort order? within the partition? within the entire cluster? what about if a node is offline? etc.

Comment: Last record inserted in the table within the cluster

Comment: Cassandra doesn't track data that way; it's not like appending to a single file. Two writes can happen at the _exact same_ microsecond, each going to two different nodes in the cluster.  Which one was "last?"  Even if you pick a way to answer the question, that's not how C* thinks about the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL&DR: [TimeUUID](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) cql3 type to the rescue!

If you have a db schema like this:

```
create table music (
  artist_id int,
  song_id timeuuid,
  song text,
  primary key (artist_id, song_id)
) with clustering order by (song_id desc);
```

Note these changes to your original schema:

- `uuid` changed to `timeuuid`
- clustering key is sorted in reverse

The table contains some data in it:

```
 artist_id | dateOf(song_id)          | song
-----------+--------------------------+------
         1 | 2015-05-29 13:25:15+0300 |  baz
         1 | 2015-05-29 13:25:11+0300 |  bar
         1 | 2015-05-29 13:25:06+0300 |  foo
         2 | 2015-05-29 13:25:19+0300 |  qux
```

To get the latest song_id for a fixed artist_id, you can run query like:

```
select artist_id,dateOf(song_id),song from music where artist_id=1 limit 1;
```

Comment: That works within a partition, but OP stated in comments that the desired behavior is to get the "last record inserted" across the entire cluster (all partitions).  While I think using TimeUUID is a good suggestion in this case, to get the desired behavior one must assume/enusre that the values are generated correctly, consistently, and that there's no clock skew between the clients generating them. It's not quite a magic bullet.

Comment: William, u mean to say, if all my nodes are properly synced with time, then TimeUUID will give me unique and accurate results, right?